# Invariants of a $kG$-module via its comoposition series, when does $M^P \supsetneq N^P$ hold for a $p$-group for $N\subseteq M$ maximal?

Tags: finite-groups, modules, invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $k$ a field, $M$ a $kG$-module, $M^G$ the invariants of $M$ under $G$, $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ where $p = \text{char}(k)$, $N$ a maximal submodule of $M$ and $S$ the trivial simple $kG$-module. One can show that
\begin{align*}
M^G \supsetneq N^G \Leftrightarrow M^P \supsetneq N^P \text{ and } M/N \cong S.
\end{align*}
Additionaly if $M^G\supsetneq N^G$ then $\text{dim} M^G/N^G = 1$. Using this one could compute the invariants $M^G$ of $M$ via the composition series of $M$. Now my question is, if there is any way to determine $M^P \supsetneq N^P$ for a $p$-group?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks!

Comment: Standard homological algebra tells you that this happens if and only if there is a nonzero map map of modules from S to M/N that lifts back to M.  There isn't much more to say than that, though if you are assuming that M/N=S, then there is such a nonzero map if and only if M is the direct sum of N and S.

Comment: Keep in mind that the dimension of the invariants is just counting the number of occurrences of the trivial module as a SUBmodule.